# Respository code deployment to multiple cluster with different configuration

Tags: github, kubernetes, workflow, pipeline

**Issue/References Needed**

I am looking for a setup where a repository code could be deployed to multiple clusters and all cluster are working on different configurations, I want to understand the possibility of going this using GitHub.

I tried looking for some solution on the internet but was unable to find any referenced article which can support this. Any references could be quite helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see this two materials ([link1](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/clusters/), [link2](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/multiple_kubernetes_clusters.html))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to create multiple deployments from the same container image in the same namespace with different configurations.

These Documentations helped me:

- [Doc 1](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/)
- [Doc 2](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesstrategicmerge/)